# HTML::TokeParser finding tags _until_ a certain tag

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I need to read an html file and find a certain paragraph tag, with specific text in it.  Once I find that tag, I then want the text from all the next tags *until* I find a table tag

Example:

```
<asdf>
</asdf>
<p>THE SIGNAL TO GET INFO</p>
    <something>some good stuff in here</something>
<p>something else</p>
<ul>
    <li>something good in here for sure</li>
    <li>this too</li>
</ul>
<table> I DON'T WANT THIS </table>
```

I can find the first Paragraph tag with HTML::TokeParser like this:

```
my $description = "";
my $tp = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$content) || die "Can't open: $!";

while (my $token = $tp->get_tag("p")) {
    my $paragraph = $tp->get_trimmed_text("/p");
    if ($paragraph =~ /On this page/) {
        until ((my $stop = $tp->get_token)->[1] eq "table") {
            if ( $stop->[0] eq "S" ) {
                print $stop->[0],"\n";
            }
        }
        return $description;
    } 
}
```

I've tried the above code... but something is desperately wrong with it, since it won't even compile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call $tp->get_token, storing the data until you see `["S", "table"…]`

You say you couldn't get this to work.  Can you explain why/what you did see?  Perhaps provide a full example for people to play with.

Well, you didn't provide example output, so I made some assumptions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $content = "<asdf>
</asdf>
<p>THE SIGNAL TO GET INFO</p>
    <something>some good stuff in here</something>
<p>something else</p>
<ul>
    <li>something good in here for sure</li>
    <li>this too</li>
</ul>
<table> I DON'T WANT THIS </table>
";

my $description = "";
my $tp = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$content) || die "Can't open: $!";

while (my $token = $tp->get_tag("p")) {
    my $paragraph = $tp->get_trimmed_text("/p");
    if ($paragraph =~ /THE SIGNAL TO GET INFO/) {
      while (my $toke = $tp->get_token)
      {
        last if ($toke->[1] eq "table");
#       print "<$toke->[0]> <$toke->[1]> <$toke->[2]> <$toke->[3]> <$toke->[4]>\n";
#       print " <".join("><",@{$toke->[3]}).">\n";
        if ($toke->[0] eq "T" ) {
                my $text = $toke->[1];
                $description .= $text;
        }
      }
      print $description;
      last;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
    some good stuff in here
something else

    something good in here for sure
    this too
```

Comment: Yep. spectacular stuff. Thank you very much.